# How to check if container div hides something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine, that we have a container div with **overflow:hidden** style.

How can we check, if it actually hides something now?

Comment: You can compare `height` of element with its `scrollHeight` property. But you need to filter if this element has overflow hidden set too. Now it's really depending what you are expecting

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: Are you checking for elements, text or both?

Comment: Everything that is possible for div to contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.height()` will do if you check for child elements height:

```js
if($('#container').height() < $('#container > div').height()){
  $('pre').html($('#container').height()+"<----container|children--->" +$('#container > div').height());
}
```

```css
#container{height:50px; background:red; overflow:hidden;}
#container div{height:200px; width:100px; background:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div></div>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

`scrollHeight` can be used to have a check for scrollHeight due to text's overflow.

As in the comments this does just checks the height which won't be available when height is not set on the child element, as suggested in the comments that you should check for the `scrollHeight` which can return you the inner content is overflowed or not.

So in my opinion this should be the correct way:

```js
if($('#container').height() < $('#container')[0].scrollHeight){
  $('pre').html($('#container').height()+"<----.height()|.scrollHeight--->" +$('#container')[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

```css
#container{height:50px; background:red; overflow:hidden;}
#container div{height:200px; width:100px; background:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p><p>dummy text</p>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: that's nice...it never occurred to me

Comment: That's not always some elements that can make a container overflowed. What about textnodes ? What about content overflowing on container width?

Comment: I just posted an answer to include width.  No clue how to just handle text though.

Comment: @fauxserious See Rory's answer (or mine) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `height` of element with its `scrollHeight` property and `width` with its `scrollWidth` property:

```js
var $divs = $('div').filter(function(){
    return  $(this).css('overflow') === "hidden";
});

$divs.toggleClass('overflowed', function(){
    return $(this).height() < $(this).prop('scrollHeight') || $(this).width() < $(this).prop('scrollWidth');
});
```

```css
div {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.overflowed {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>tteterre
    er<br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br>
        
    erz
    r
    </div>
```

Now you could create your own pseudo selector:

```js
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
  overflowed: $.expr.createPseudo ? $.expr.createPseudo(function() {
      return function(el) {
        return getComputedStyle(el).overflow === "hidden" && (el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth || el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight);
      };
    }) :
    // support: jQuery <1.8
    function(el) {
      return getComputedStyle(el).overflow === "hidden" && (el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth || el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight);
    }
});

$('div:overflowed').addClass('isOverflowed');
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  display: block;
}
.isOverflowed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>doesn't overflow</div>
<div>there is little content overflowing by height</div>
<div>content element oveflowing <span>GET IT</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `clientHeight` of the element to its `scrollHeight`:

```
var container = $('.container')[0];
var hasOverflowed = container.scrollWidth > container.clientWidth || container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight;
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rvq6dejc/1/)

You can also easily convert this in to it's own jQuery method:

```
$.fn.hasOverflowed = function() {
    var el = this[0];
    return el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth || el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight;
}

if ($('#myElement').hasOverflowed()) {
    // Run to the hills!
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rvq6dejc/2/)

Comment: I like the idea of a jQuery prototype method, *but* i don't like then the use of none jq method inside it ;)  Just my opinion of course. As side note,only handles one element per matched set

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$(id).is(":visible")
```

The above code return true if the container is visible otherwise it will return false

Comment: OP is asking about the content inside the div, not the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for a child element inside a parent, you'll need to compare the dimensions to see if the child is greater than the parent.

```
var parentWidth = $('.parent').width();
var parentHeight = $('.parent').height();
var childWidth = $('.child').width();
var childHeight = $('.child').height();

if(childWidth > parentWidth || childHeight > parentHeight){
   //something is hidden
};
```

What I'm not confident about is if `.height()` and `.width()` will grab the true height and width of child or just the boundaries that the parent provides.

If this is only text inside of the div, I'm not sure how to check that.